# How to deploy multiple apps under the same url using S3 on AWS?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have several angular/react apps that I want to deploy under the same url on AWS with S3. One of my angular apps is already working fine when I go to mysite.com. The app works as expected. I want to avoid the angular router, and when a user goes to mysite.com/reactapp then the react app is loaded. or when going to mysite.com/otherangularapp then the other angular app is loaded. How can you one do this using S3 and other AWS resources?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you have any other option then using Angular Router.

Other options might be using subdomains, having each reactjs application in a different bucket and using Route53 to point to different buckets.

```
App1 - mysite.com/
App2 - reactapp.mysite.com/
App3 - otherangularapp.mysite.com/
```

Comment: Ok cool, thanks for the suggestion. I have a feeling thats what I need to do too....